# Value for key is nil. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, key-value

Good morning, I made an IBAction method which saves some objects to an array:

```
-(IBAction)saveToFav:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *newDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[newDefaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorites"] copyItems:YES];

    // check if array already contains an object

    if (![favorites containsObject:self.title])
    {
        [favorites addObject:self.title];
    }
    [newDefaults setObject:favorites forKey:@"favorites"];
}
```

However, when I call this method app crashes with error:

> [NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray getObjects:range:]: value for key
>   favorites of object 0x8939030 is nil'

Why this happens ?
Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your data (favorites) has not been written to your defaults.You can forcesave your defaults by running this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: You probably already figured this out but .... this correct in your case:    [newDefaults synchronize];

Comment: Ok, but where should I use it in my code ?
Here?
`NSUserDefaults *newDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[newDefaults synchronized];

favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[newDefaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorites"] copyItems:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

newDefaults is nil for key "favorites".

Comment: As in you havent written anything to your NSUserDefaults

Comment: I added this code (it runs when app finishes loading):
`NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[defaults setObject:array forKey:@"favorites"];`
array is empty. But It didn't change anything :)

Comment: for key favorites, sorry didn't change it here

Comment: did you synchronize your defaults?

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[newDefaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favorites"] copyItems:YES];
```

`nil` is being assigned to `favorites`.  The reason for this is that `newDefaults` is only just built on the previous line and is empty.

Comment: I thought that once you created key "favorites" (for example in another class) I will be able to use it in all NSUserDefaults objects I created in my app. So I should use only one NSUserDefaults ?

Comment: It's fine to create another handle to the defaults, but you need to make sure that the value is being added _before_ this code gets run.

Answer (score 1):

When your app finishes loading add this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
[defaults setObject:array forKey:@"favorites"]; 
[defaults synchronize];
```